# Difficulties to display simple value ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I Know that it is really a very simple question and I'm sorry, I know using ggplot2 for complex matrix, but when I've this type of information, i have no way to display it nicely as I made for the others.

How to ggplot k ?

Edit : No error obtained but just an empty plot

```
k=structure(list(`11` = 76.2025316455696, `16` = 0.907172995780591, 
        `17` = 84.3670886075949, `12` = 19.957805907173, `15` = 5.44303797468354, 
        `13` = 5.44303797468354, `14` = 19.0506329113924, `18` = 3.62869198312236), .Names = c("11", 
    "16", "17", "12", "15", "13", "14", "18"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

Ineed to use ggplot in order to assign color for each category as follows

```
cat.colors <- brewer.pal(8, "Set1") # assign a color for each level of your factor variable Sous_Categorie 
names(cat.colors) <- c("11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18") 
label=c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4","cat5","cat6","cat7","cat8")
mycolourscale <- scale_fill_manual(name = "Catégories",values = cat.colors, breaks=1:8, labels=as.character(label))
```

Comment: What code generated that error? You've just given us the data...

Comment: ggplot(k), I need to precise the X and Y ? how to transform it for ggplot ? thanks.

Comment: With that `k`, `ggplot(k)` does not generate that error message about "class matrix". What did you do?

Comment: Also, which bits of k are you trying to plot as X and Y coordinates? As points or lines? Are the column labels (11, 16, 17 etc) the X coordinates and the decimal numbers the Y coordinates? Or what?

Comment: from 11 to 18i s the X and the (76.20253 0.907173 84.36709 19.95781 5.443038 5.443038 19.05063 3.628692) is the Y. I need GGplot in order to assign colors for each bar. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to reshape your data a bit in order to make this work (`k` is from your `dput`):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
k = data.frame(X = names(k), Y = t(k)) #reshape your data
#then define the colour scale as you provided
cat.colors <- brewer.pal(8, "Set1") # assign a color for each level of your factor variable
names(cat.colors) <- c("11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18") 
label=c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4","cat5","cat6","cat7","cat8")
mycolourscale <- scale_fill_manual(name = "Catégories",
values = cat.colors, breaks=1:8, labels=as.character(label))
#make the plot
ggplot(k, aes(X, Y))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = X))+
   mycolourscale
```

Which results in:
[image]

And if you want a legend label (but same palette):

```
ggplot(k, aes(X, Y))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = X))+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1')+theme_bw()
```

[image]